# I'm trying use flutter svg, but load with black svg

Tags: svg, flutter

I'm trying to use Flutter SVG dependency, i put in the svg in assets, set in pubspec.yaml, and set in my widget, but, the svg load with black container

I've already tried change the svg, and the another svg works fine, but the other not...

```
    final Widget svg = SvgPicture.asset(assetName, semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo');
```

the svg in flutter

[Here the svg](https://codepen.io/codepeniolucas/pen/LYYLROb)

My expected response was colored svg like the link in codepen, but i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGNqK.jpg)

Answer (score 29):

This is probably happened because of the corrupted SVG files from the internet. I faced this problem earlier and tried many ways to solve it. But finally, I solved it with the help of this software, [**svgcleaner**](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner).

Download the application into your OS, from [***here***](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/releases)

After installation,

1. import your SVG.

[image: importsvg]

2. Click run.

[image: run]

3. Success! Here you can see your SVGs' cleaned successfully.

[image: success]

After cleaning, you can grab those SVG files from the output folder location and add those files into your flutter app without seeing any black coloured SVG.

It works perfectly fine like this.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i already tried this, and not works.. I changed my svg to another one, and works

Comment: works like magic.

Comment: currently, you can use https://iconly.io/tools/svg-cleaner

Answer (score 4):

I found this site it solved my problem with the svg file that was out of color.

https://iconly.io/tools/svg-cleaner

Answer (score 3):

I think I am late but this might just help someone. Just make all the styles in your svg image use inline styling otherwise all colors and styling won't be rendered as the  tag is not readable by the SvgPicture.

Comment: I opened the svg in Illustrator, "File > Export". Styling  "Inline Style". I copied the "Show Code" to my svg image in VS Code. It worked for me.

Comment: @WesleyBarnes That is exactly what I am saying that you must do

Answer (score 3):

[image: Illustrator SVG Configuration]

use this configuration in illustrator before you add it to your project.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2842459/62599914-91de9c00-b8fe-11e9-8fb7-4af57d5100f7.png

Answer (score 1):

I tried this SVG asset with the latest version of `jovial_svg`, and it works great!  Here's the result:

[image: Screen Shot]

This version of `jovial_svg` should be released in a couple of days, but for now it's 1.1.4-rc.4.

(This asset helped me flesh out stylesheet support - thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that The `flutter_svg` is unable to load the css written inside `style` tag. `flutter_svg` only support inline css . **Write inline css instead of inside the `style` tag**

Answer (score 0):

If You don't have solution try to convert your image from svg to png and use:

`Image.asset('assets/images/image.png',)`

Answer (score 0):

Some SVG images uses style tag and if you try to load such image using flutter_svg, image won't render as expected. Currently flutter_svg supports styling through inline styles only and not the style tag that some of SVG files may contain (in my case, I exported image from Adobe XD and it has all styles in  tag). When you try to load such SVG images, you will get below error:

> ======== Exception caught by SVG =================================================================== The following UnimplementedError was thrown in parseSvgElement: The
>
> element is not implemented in this library.
>
> Style elements are not supported by this library and the requested SVG
> may not render as intended.
>
> If possible, ensure the SVG uses inline styles and/or attributes
> (which are supported), or use a preprocessing utility such as
> svgcleaner to inline the styles for you.

This error mentions to use inline style instead of style tag, you can use [svgcleaner](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui) (as mentioned in @Alif's answer) or similar utility to convert SVG file with inline styling.

For more detials, refer this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#check-svg-compatibility) to check SVG compatibility with flutter_svg and handling other use-cases

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cleaning the SVG file , which is not acceptable for app client to clean every SVG he need it

- **Use this SVG Plugin it solve the problem**

https://pub.dev/packages/jovial_svg

```
ScalableImageWidget.fromSISource(
              si: ScalableImageSource.fromSvgHttpUrl(
                Uri.parse(imgPath),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

delete your pubspec.lock file and do flutter clean -> flutter pub get-> run your application.

Answer (score -5):

try this:

```
Container(
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
       'assets/images/image.svg',
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Not works yet... still black color, but resolved the size

Comment: Ohh, i get a error but i dont know if i can resolved but i dont make svg, the error message is:The following UnimplementedError was thrown in parseSvgElement:
The <style> element is not implemented in this library. Style elements are not supported by this library and the requested SVG may not render as intended. If possible, ensure the SVG uses inline styles and/or attributes (which are supported), or use a preprocessing utility such as svgcleaner to inline the styles for you.
Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#62456(), name: "assets/login.svg", colorFilter: null)